# k2 component not working in joomla 1.7.3

Tags: joomla, joomla1.7, joomla-k2

Cannot create or save in k2 v2.5 in.5 joomla 1.7.3?
I am having a problem with K2 especially when it comes to creating categories and articles. The SAVE, SAVE&CLOSE or SAVE&NEW buttons in the administration part of the site don't seem to be working. When you click on them they do nothing. The only thing working is the CANCEL button.

Comment: Any javascript errors on firebug ?

Answer (score 0):

Dunno if this help, but at least it helped getting the save button work.

"As suggested if you are using joomla 1.7 and k2 2.5.5 go to joomla admin > Extensions > Plugin Manager > Disable "Smart Search - K2" plugin."

ref: https://www.gavick.com/forums/general-discussion/k2-2-5-5-problem-14690.html

Answer (score 0):

I think its installation problem , you know was there any problem when you installing k2 component? (installation problem mainly based in folder permission issue in ftp), 
I do k2 component.

Thanks